# How do we show the exponential distribution has maximal entropy on R+?

Tags: entropy, exponential-distribution

I’ve been looking around the internet, and having trouble finding a demonstration that the exponential distribution is maximal entropy on R+. I’d appreciate any points in the right direction.

Comment: This result is not true, because there does not exist any entropy-maximizing distribution overall.  A *particular* exponential distribution will maximize entropy over all distributions *having a given mean.*  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_entropy_probability_distribution#Continuous_version.

Comment: Sorry for being vague, I meant that among the distributions on R+ with finite variance, exponentials maximize entropy. I was hoping for a non Lagrange multiplier based proof... there's easy proofs of uniform and Gaussian being maximum entropy on their respective domains through non-negativity of KL-divergence, so I was hoping there was something similar for R+.

Comment: The point is that the entropy-maximizing distribution depends on what constraints you impose.  First, you *have* to impose some constraints, for otherwise there is no solution.  Second, if the constraint is anything other than specifying the mean, then the solution typically is *not* an exponential distribution.  Since constraints have to be specified, you need some approach that accommodates constraints--such as Lagrange multipliers.